# How to dynamically round off cell value for group of cell in excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have excel template file which is  excel 2016 , I want from Column E23 to E100 if some one enter any value it round off till 3 digit . Example :- 12345.123456 should convert to 12345.123 .

Bu this should only effective to that cell where any value get change . In attached picture Column E is where I want round off . Any help will be greatly appreciated .

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the value *rounded* or *truncated*? For example, should "100.345678" be "100.34**5**" or "100.34**6**"?

Comment: I want rounded , please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

To enter this event-triggered Macro, right click on the sheet tab.
Select "View Code" from the right-click drop-down menu.
Then paste the code below into the window that opens.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim C As Range

If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(5)) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each C In Intersect(Target, Columns(5))
        If IsNumeric(C.Value) And Len(C.Value) > 0 Then
            C.Value = Round(C.Value, 3)
        End If
    Next C
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much Ron , worked like charm . Much appreciate you help

Comment: One more thing could you please guide me how to add VBA code in excel 2016

Comment: @Arun What happened when you tried the method I posted in Excel 2016?

Comment: my excel sheet is dynamic , so column E could start from E22 sometime start from E30 but name of column will not change , is there any way to get column name and apply above code below cell of column E and up t0 100th down cell . Sorry for bothering you I am very new to VB . Seeking for help

Comment: @Arun You could use the `Find` method to locate the relevant cell in column E, and then construct the Range to use in the `Intersect` method above.

Comment: If you do an internet search you will find thousands of examples of using the Range.Find method. If you run into trouble integrating it, post a new question with specifics as to the problem you are having.  Include the actual code you are using; any error messages; etc. (See HELP for this forum for information as to how to ask a good question, and how to provide an example.